# Is there a way to get the data from a formattable row in Shiny when I select / click it

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

I use the [formattable](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable) package in Shiny in R and I am quite happy with it.
However I might want to select a row from what I am presenting with it.
Is there a way of selecting a row from a formattable?

(i know that DT::Datatable for example has a way to do that)

Comment: You may try the upcoming release of formattable v0.2 (https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable/tree/v0.2) in which as.datatable is defined to convert a formattable data frame to DT datatable with most formatting preserved.

Comment: I will work up an example, but please note `v0.2` is not yet released so might change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm also interested in using a combination of `formattable` and `datatable` in `shiny` apps. Therefore, I had a closer look at the github repo of `formattable` and found the issue [Possible to add sorting and filtering to formattable?](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable/issues/27):

> [...]  I was wondering if it is possible to easily integrate dataTable features like sorting and filtering (as implemented in RStudio's DT library). [...]

The issue was closed by Kun Ren  with the comment:

> I guess it's better use DT instead. formattable is currently only designed for static content presentation with formatting applied to columns. It would be some major changes to make it more interactive, and probably would become the same with DT finally, and that's not the goal of this package though.

Answer (score 4):

With the pending `v0.2`, combining `DT::datatable` and `formattable` is easy.  Here is an example.

```
# need v0.2, so uncomment below to install
# devtools::install_github("renkun-ken/formattable@v0.2")

library(formattable)

as.datatable(
  formattable(
    mtcars,
    list(mpg = formatter(
      "span",
      style = x ~ style(
        display = "block",
        "border-radius" = "4px",
        "padding-right" = "4px",
        color = "white",
        "background-color" = rgb(x/max(x), 0, 0))
      )
    )
  )
)
```